# Do two equal spans have the same basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

So I'm trying to solve the following question: 
Suppose that $\{A, B\}$ is a basis for a vector space $W$. Prove that $\{X, Y\}$ is also a basis for $W$, where $X = 2A + 3B$ and $Y = 3A − 5B$. 
I just proved that $\operatorname{Span}(X,Y) = \operatorname{Span}(A,B)$, but I'm not really sure how to go from here. Does having equal spans mean that their basis are equal? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: By the definition of a basis, you should check that the set is linearly independent and it spans $W$. You said you checked the span, then you should verify that the set is linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

If the two spans are the same, then they span the same vector space.  A vector space can have any number of bases, but the number of elements in any basis is always the same, called the *dimension* of the vector space.  Any basis for the first span will be a basis for the second span, since they are the same vector space.

Note that once you know the dimension, say $n$, any set of $n$ linearly independent vectors, or $n$ vectors that span, will form a basis.